# Task Manager is receiving messages out of order

Tags: apache-flink, stream-processing

I'm reading messages from file and applying some operators before writing into Sink, noticed task manage is getting messages out of order for a given key. How to fix this? Am i doing soimething wrong? Please check my source file format and code below. Thanks!

```
customer_id - timestamp - event_seq
1 t1 e1
1 t2 e2
2 t1 e1
2 t2 e2
1 t3 e3


        DataStream<String> source = createTextFileSourceFromConfig(env);

        source.map(new MapFunction<String, JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public JSONObject map(String s) throws Exception {
                return new JSONObject(s);
            }
        }).keyBy(new KeySelector<JSONObject, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(JSONObject event) {
                return event.get("id").toString();
            }
        }).filter(new InitialFilter())...
```

In example above, Task manager is receiving <1 t3 e3> as the first message for id=1. Appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a read parallelism > 1, then there's no guarantee about the order of the records being received by downstream operators, as the input file(s) can be split between the sources, which are executing in parallel. So you could have the source for the last chunk of a file start emitting lines before the first chunk.

Comment: Just to add: splits are used to increase the throughput and there is inherently not a way to guarantee orderness, since that would sacrifice a big portion of the gain. If you need in-order data, set the parallelism of your source to 1 and be aware of the decreased throughput. Also note, that a subsequent keyBy with (parallelism > 1) will only retain the orderness per key.